# Jmeter - get current date and time

Tags: jmeter

I want to get the current date and time as example date: 11/10/2014 and time 8:30 am or 6:00 pm and pass it as parameters to my Jmeter test. Can some help me do this.

Comment: if you asked this question few years ago I'd have jmeter installed and I would answer this. But something along this you should do. 1. Create a beanshell processor and inside execute piece of java code `new Date()` and store it in a variable, and just reuse that variable in your test.

Comment: I tried. I am not very familiar with java but tried   ${__BeanShell(new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(new Date()))}. It throws me an error "jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval In file: inline evaluation of: ``11/20/2014 09:25:34 ;'' Encountered "0" at line 1, column 12.".

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/3920295/user3920295 It would be good for JMeter community if you could accept the answer stackoverflow.com/a/27048364/460802 so that users are confident with right method. Thanks

Comment: Another useful link in this context: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62231892/4398100

Answer (score 77):

Use [__time](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) function:

- ${__time(dd/MM/yyyy,)}
- ${__time(hh:mm a,)}

Since JMeter 3.3, there are two new functions that let you compute a time:

[__timeShift](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__timeShift)

```
  "The timeShift function returns a date in the given format with the specified amount of seconds, minutes, hours, days or months added" and
```

[__RandomDate](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomDate)

```
  "The RandomDate function returns a random date that lies between the given start date and end date values."
```

Since JMeter 4.0:

[dateTimeConvert](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__dateTimeConvert)

```
Convert a date or time from source to target format
```

If you're looking to learn jmeter correctly, this [book](https://leanpub.com/master-jmeter-from-load-test-to-devops) will help you.

Comment: Is there any way to add a couple of hours to this value to set the time stamp in the future?

Comment: To mutate the date, you could try using __javascript instead, e.g., to get a timestamp 6 hours in the future: ${__javaScript(new Date(new Date().setHours(new Date().getHours()+6)).toISOString())}

Comment: For those finding this question in the future:  JMeter 3.3 has two new functions that let you compute a time:  __timeShift - "The timeShift function returns a date in the given format with the specified amount of seconds, minutes, hours, days or months added" and __RandomDate - "The RandomDate function returns a random date that lies between the given start date and end date values."

Answer (score 31):

it seems to be the java SimpleDateFormat : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

here are some tests i did around 11:30pm on the 20th of May 2015

```
${__time(dd-mmm-yyyy HHmmss)} 20-032-2015 233224
${__time(d-MMM-yyyy hhmmss)}  20-May-2015 113224
${__time(dd-m-yyyy hhmmss)}   20-32-2015 113224
${__time(D-M-yyyy hhmmss)}    140-5-2015 113224
${__time(DD-MM-yyyy)}         140-05-2015
```

Comment: Is there any way to add a couple of hours to this value to set the time stamp in the future?

Comment: There is no easy way... but there are two hard ways :

Comment: 1) use a beanshell interpreter to set a date using java (see the comments on the original question).  2) set the time into one or more variables and use a tedious series of jMeter functions (intNum and split) to generate the time string you want.

Comment: In which module we need to use this function in jmeter

Comment: @RajeshOm in this question it is being used as a "Value" in the "Parameters" tab of the "HTTP Request" module.  I often put dates in a "User Defined Variables" module to use later... but it can be used in almost any field in almost any module.

Answer (score 25):

JMeter is using java SimpleDateFormat

For UTC with timezone use this

```
${__time(yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ssX)}
```

Comment: Is there any way to add a couple of hours to this value to set the time stamp in the future?

Answer (score 12):

Use `${__time(yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss)}` to convert time into a particular timeformat.
Here are other formats that you can use:

```
yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS
yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss
```

You can use Z character to get milliseconds too.
For example:

```
yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ssZ => 2017-01-25T10:29:00-0700
yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z' => 2017-01-25T10:28:49.549Z
```

Most of the time `yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'` is required in some APIs. It is better to know how to convert time into this format.

Answer (score 8):

Actually, for UTC I used `Z` instead of `X`, e.g.

```
${__time(yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ssZ)}
```

which gave me:

```
2017-09-14T09:24:54-0400
```

Answer (score 6):

Use this format:
${__time(yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SS'Z')}

Which will give you:
2018-01-16T08:32:28.75Z

Answer (score 4):

Should have double quotes surrounding the `${}`

```
String todaysDate = "${__time(yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z')}";
```