# Fetch current time in 24 hours format in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

How can I get current time in 24 hours format in JMeter.

I tried `${__time(hh:mm a,)}` but it results in AM/PM format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [How to Use JMeter Functions](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) guide  JMeter's [__time()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) function output can be controlled via [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class patterns.

Looking into JavaDoc:

- you don't need `a` letter
- you need to use capital `H` for 0-24 hours or lowercase `k` for 1-23 hours

So change function to `${__time(HH:mm,)}` and that should be it

[image: Time in 24h format]

Answer (score 0):

In Apache JMeter 5.2, current time can be captured in **User defined variable** and then used in Rest payloads as following screenshot:

```
expression - ${__timeShift(yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'.000+05:30',,PT0S,,)}

output - "2020-06-06T18:10:59.000+05:30"
```

[image]

Here, date and time format can be changed as per the need.

Once current date and time is captured in user defined variable then it can be used as `"${now-date-time}"` in REST requests.

It could also be possible that we face a scenario where there should be gap of, let's say, 1second between start time and end time while constructing request. In such case, following expressions can help:

```
now-date-time : ${__timeShift(yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'.000+05:30',,PT0S,,)}

now-date-time-plus-one-second : ${__timeShift(yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'.000+05:30',,PT1S,,)}
```

Following example better explains it:

[image]