# jmeter- How to get current date and time in seconds

Tags: jmeter

i want to calculate current time in seconds and use it as a parameter in my jmeter test plan. By default the time is in milliseconds.
Can somebody help me please.

Comment: below link might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27043029/jmeter-get-current-date-and-time

Comment: @SnehalPatel : checked that already. that is useful when somebody wants it in a specific format like DD/MM/YY or DD-MM-YY.

Comment: this link could help - https://stackoverflow.com/a/62231892/4398100

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [__time](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) function with format string as `/1000`.

```
 ${__time(/1000,)} - to get time in seconds
```

From JMeter DOCs:

> For example, "/1000" returns the current time in seconds since the epoch.

Comment: yeah Naveen..checked that. but my application supports date in only seconds. i just wanted to know about any other function or method which can change it to seconds while running the test.

Answer (score 18):

You can use [__time() function](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time), by default it returns current time in milliseconds since beginning of [Unix epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)

If you need this time in "seconds" precision - just divide it by 1000 using i.e. [__javaScript() function](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__javaScript)

So:

- `${__time(,)}` will return current time in milliseconds
- `${__javaScript(${__time(,)} / 1000,)}` - will return current time in seconds
- `${__javaScript(Math.round(${__time(,)} / 1000),)}` - will round up the current time in seconds to the nearest integer

Demo:

[image: JMeter time javascript functions]

Reference materials:

- [JMeter Functions and Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)
- [SimpleDateFormat patterns](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)
- [How to Use JMeter Functions - Part III](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii)

Answer (score 0):

Use __timeShift() and __jexl3() functions combination

with __timeShift() you will get the date in past/future in milliseconds since start of the Unix epoch
[see screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5SPM.png)

and with __jexl3() you can simply divide the resulting value by 1000 to get the value in seconds

[see screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJokU.png)