# How to get next date (Epoch format) in JMeter with _time function

Tags: jmeter, epoch

I have script where current date and current date + 4 days need to be pass as URL param in https req.
I want to avoid groovy script or other script here to generate the next date.

To get current system date in epoch format I am using `${__time(/1000,)}`

But not sure how to get the next date in this epoch format `1588926501` with using _time or _timeshift option.

Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

Go for [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy), the relevant syntax would be something like:

```
${__groovy((new Date().plus(4).getTime() / 1000).longValue(),)}
```

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- Groovy [Date.plus()](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html#plus(int))
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Answer (score 0):

Try using : `${__javaScript(Math.round(${__timeShift(,,P4D,,)}/1000),)}`

You can also try options from [JavaScript function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__javaScript) on this [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42364226/jmeter-how-to-get-current-date-and-time-in-seconds)

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/6619203/raj Thanks for help. But this is giving me time like '1.589524255E9' and expected format is '1589178654'. Could you plz help?

Comment: You probably need to do this in two steps:


1. ${__timeShift(,,P4D,,epochTimeInMS)}

and then 
2. ${__javaScript('${epochTimeInMS}'.slice(0\,10))}