# Getting date stamp to use as part of string in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to get the current date and add it as part of a string, but it is not working. This is what I have:

In User Defined Variables

```
currentDate    ${__time(dd/MM/yyyy)}
```

And then later:

```
CurrentDate = vars.get("currentDate");
TestFile = vars.get("testFile-" + CurrentDate + ".txt");

f = new FileOutputStream(TestFile, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Do you **really** have variable called i.e. `testFile-31/03/2016.txt`?
2. Do you expect to write something into file called like above?

Actually there are some reserved characters which cannot be used in file names, i.e.

> < (less than)
>
> > (greater than)
>
> : (colon)
>
> " (double quote)
>
> / (forward slash)
>
> \ (backslash)
>
> | (vertical bar or pipe)
>
> ? (question mark)
>
> * (asterisk)

I would suggest to:

1. Reconsider your pattern
2. Remove `vars.get` at all  so your code would look like:

   ```
   import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

   sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
   TestFile = "testFile-" + sdf.format(new Date()) + ".txt";
   f = new FileOutputStream(TestFile, true);
   ```

References:

- [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx) - file naming conventions, they're Windows based, however should be similar for all operating systems which comply with [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX)
- [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) - guidelines and how-to's for developing, running and troubleshooting Beanshell scripts in JMeter.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `$` in front of the `{`.

See

[This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27043029/jmeter-get-current-date-and-time)

[Jmeter Functions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time)

Comment: Thank you. I've changed that now and it still doesn't seem to be working though.

Comment: is currentDate getting set? Check with a `Debug Sampler` or `log.info(CurrentDate)` in what I assume is BeanShell

Comment: The second part of the code there is in a beanshell.

Comment: Ok, the date is getting set correctly in the debug processer, but the TestFile is not, so must be an issue with:
    TestFile = vars.get("testFile-" + CurrentDate + ".txt");

Comment: do you actually have a variable in that or are you simply trying to make a filename? Remember that `vars.get` will only find a variable that has already been declared. I **think** what you're trying to do is just `TestFile = "testFile-" + CurrentDate + ".txt";`

Comment: yes I think that might be what I want. The "testFile-" part is a var of a file path location, which is also in UDV. So I separated that into it's own vars.get and have tried: 'TFile = testFile + CurrentDate + ".txt' but I'm finding the file still is not being created

Comment: ah. Try `TestFile = vars.get("testFile") + "-" + CurrentDate + "".txt";`